# How to include saml in aspnet core 2.1 MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, saml-2.0, tls1.2

I am working on aspnetcore 2.1 MVC application , the requirement is to include TLS1.2 and Saml. 
I am new to MVC world, kindly let me know what is the best way to include in AspnetCore 2.1 MVC web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [SAML client side](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) stack.

TLS is part of the IIS server infrastructure, not part of SAML.